# How to delimitate a view onto the preview to take a selfie?

Tags: kotlin, preview, android-camera2

i am implementing an android application in kotlin and i have to take a selfie . I don't want the selfie to take all the screen size so I've using a Preview and then draw a view on it . Here is the xml file  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SelfieCamera">

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/preview_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/buttons_layout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/buttons_layout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/_110sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/dotted_border"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_55sdp"
        android:background="@color/translucide"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1">
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My purpose is to capture the selfie on the view layout .. how could I figure it out ?

```
        private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(requireContext())

//        val aspectRatio = aspectRatio(binding.previewView.width,binding.previewView.height)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            // Preview
            val preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(binding.previewView.surfaceProvider)
                }
```